# Why my rendering of this site's font gives different results?

Tags: html, css, fonts

[This site](https://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor), according to a plugin, uses `monospace 12px` on its text editor (the part to the left). I tried replicating the same font with CSS locally, but the results are very different:

[image: b]
[image: a]

The font, as rendered on their site, looks much thinner than my rendering. How can I replicate the same font ientically?

Edit: I should've said that I don't use bold at all, and changing the `font-weight` to 100 has no effect.

Comment: any inherited `font-weight:bold` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the font-weight numerically, you'll need to research what weights the font supports.

```
font-weight: 900;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect this text element on both pages in your browser's Developer toolbar and look at computed CSS styles for them. Most likely, as Khanh TO has stated, you've got additional `font-weight` style defined locally that's applied to this text.